# How to append li into ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

> i have array values. i need to insert array values into li ,after that
>   it will be appended into ul.

### HTML

```
<div>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
 </div>
```

Array value x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Need Output

```
<div>
    <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li></ul>
    <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li></ul>
 </div>
```

I have tried some thing i wont work. fiddle **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/7/)**

Comment: Check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

x.forEach(function(num){
  $('ul').append('<li>' + num + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul></ul>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Or, perhaps:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$('ul').html(function() {
  return '<li>' + x.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul></ul>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method which can also accept an array of DOMElements/jQuery Objects:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$("div ul").append(x.map(function (el) {
    return $('<li>').text(el);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Should mention that is using the .map on the Array.prototype, rather than the jQuery .map

Comment: @RGraham Yes. If IE8 is needed `$.map` should be used instead.

Comment: @RGraham You probably confused `$.map` (static method) and `$.fn.map` (instance method).

Comment: I did initially visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ but it returned a 404. Probably a typo!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("div").children().each(function () {
    $(this).append(function () {
        return $.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (i, val) {
            return "<li>" + i + "</li>";
        });
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each elements and append like this

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$("div ul").each(function() {
    var ul = this;
    $.each(x, function(i, val) {
        $(ul).append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/12/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$("div ul").each(function () {
    for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        $(this).append("<li>" + x[i] + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
var x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$("div ul").each(function () {
    var $ul = $(this);
    $.each(x, function() {
        $ul.append($("<li/>").text(this));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/srsggcrz/14/)